# Flight moved by 24 hours 9 days before departure. What happend? What are my options?

Tags: schedule-change

I booked a flight from Vienna to Tokyo through Helsinki on the 10th of December. The flight was supposed to leave on the 21st of December, but has been moved to the 22nd. I was informed of this on the 12th.

The flight is managed through British Airways, and was supposed to be with Finnair for the first, and Japan Airways for the second part.
But now both flights are with Finnair.

(Return flights have not changed and are both with Finnair).

I'm not looking to raise hell. I'm still arriving before christmas, but this is a minor inconvenience and I am losing one day of my stay.

But what are my options now?

Comment: Was there any change to the first leg of your flight?  Sometimes if the first leg of an international flight gets cancelled, it requires pushing the whole trip back by a full day.

Comment: The whole flight has been moved by 24 hours, including the departure time of the first leg. In addition the second leg has changed the airline (JAL --> FIN). (When buying I had the option of either on the original date at the same price with a 10 minute difference in arrival times)

Comment: Ask the airline, they must give you the options (and the leaflet about EU rights). You have some right (changes 9 days before the flight), OTOH not so many rights, and probably cancelling the booking with full refund is not the best option in this period. By phone you can discuss better options (e.g. anticipate, other airlines, ...). Automatic notifications are often not the best options (for most of people).

Comment: Do you have the relevant flight numbers? What travel class did you book? There's still a relevant VIE-HEL-NRT combination (Finnair + JAL) on the 21st, and still available seats in coach, so I'm not sure I understand why they would have done that.

Comment: Who did you book with and who informed you about the change? BA still sells seats for the 21st December with a stop in Helsinki.

Comment: What options do you seek? Do you want to fly on the original date? Do you like to get a refund on the ticket?

Comment: I gave them a call and now I'm back on my original flight. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, when a flight gets removed from the schedule, the airline automatically rebooks you to something that *could* be good for you, but not necessarily is. How would they know if you would prefer to go earlier, later, or not at all?

If you call them, and tell them that you don't like the option they selected for you, they are typically willing to go with you through all other available options.
My experience is they are rather generous, as long as there are seats in your preferred alternative schedule, they give it to you for free. However, your mileage may vary; my specific experience so far is with United, Southwest, Lufthansa, and Avianca, and others might be less supportive.
They also typically offer you to reverse the whole trip, and you get all your  oney back; however, this is rarely interesting, as any other flights are now probably more expensive.

So call them and ask nicely for alternatives, and hopefully you can pick your favorite schedule. Don't expect them to fly an extra plane for you though...

Comment: I did give them a call. The person on the phone wondered why it was moved as well, but now I'm back on my original flight. Thank you and all the others that recommended giving them a call.

Comment: I traveled on the original date. In Helsinki my name was called out and they told me they were overbooked. They offered a hotel and some form of compensation if I took their offer. I planned to take it, but took to long thinking about options. Someone else took it.